# Can I have a field in a @Document that is of the Class type?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to persist a document to MongoDB. I'm using Spring-Data-MongoDB to declare `@Document`s. There is one particular document that is giving me problems. Below is an example the problematic document that has a field of the type `java.lang.Class`.

```
@Document
public class Value {
    @Id
    private Class<? extends I> clazz;
    private Integer value;
    ...
}
```

The error that I get is below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.Class constructor accessible
```

My current solution is to use a `String` instead of `Class`. I would appreciate any help on solving this issue of not being to use fields that are of the type `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why would you want to store the Class like that and not just the name?
2. You could add a converter to convert the Class to a String when you save it and back to a Class when you load your entity.

Comment: Because each class that implements `I` interface have a different value (that can be changed during runtime). Hence the need to persist the value so that the an implementation can retrieve the associated value.

Comment: I see.  That makes sense.  You'll just want to store that class name then.  Storing the class doesn't really get you anything but bugs.

Comment: I agree. How it is actually stored does not matter. From the perspective of coding, it is simpler (and maybe more efficient) to use `Class`; (e.g., a map lookup can be `map.put(clazz, value)` instead of  `map.put(clazz.getName(), value)`. I'll try out the converter approach, maybe it will work transparently.